# How to import javascript modules and bundle into a single js file with rollup?

Tags: javascript, node-modules, rollupjs, eleventy, jamstack

I have javascript functions I want to run both server-side and client side. The server side uses `node.js` and can handle imports just fine.

However, the client side i want a single script tag with inlined javascript. To achieve that goal I understood that I needed a bundler to pull the modules into the main script file. I chose rollup to do that job.

Here's an example of what I've tried. I've made a module `test.js`. it's a simple function that returns a string:

```
// test.js

const test = () => {
    return 'testing'
}

module.exports = test
```

and here's the main javascript file, `main.js`. The file I want to pull the `test.js` function into:

```
// main.js

import test from "/test.js"

console.log(test())
```

Here's what i'd like `main.js` to look like after bundling:

```
// main.js

const test = () => {
    return 'testing'
}

console.log(test())
```

I'd like to simply pull the function into the file.

Instead rollup produces this:

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(require('../../../../../../../js/test.js')) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['../../../../../../../js/test'], factory) :
    (global = typeof globalThis !== 'undefined' ? globalThis : global || self, factory(global.test));
}(this, (function (test) { 'use strict';

    function _interopDefaultLegacy (e) { return e && typeof e === 'object' && 'default' in e ? e : { 'default': e }; }

    var test__default = /*#__PURE__*/_interopDefaultLegacy(test);

    console.log(test__default['default']());

})));
```

The code is much larger than before, and crucially the module isn't incorporated into the main file. It's still a module, but with different syntax. Rollup has a number of output options, all produce similar results.

Here's my `rollup.config.js` file:

```
// rollup.config.js

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/scripts/main.js',
        output: {
            name: 'main',
            file: "public/scripts/main.js",
            format: 'umd'
        }
    }
]
```

Of course, this is the expected output for somebody who understands what's going on. But I don't understand.

**How do I merge a javascript into one file at build time?**

**is there a simpler solution I'm overlooking?**

Edit: Using the `commonjs` module and setting the output format to `iife` results in the following:

```
// main.js

(function (test) {
    'use strict';

    function _interopDefaultLegacy (e) { return e && typeof e === 'object' && 'default' in e ? e : { 'default': e }; }

    var test__default = /*#__PURE__*/_interopDefaultLegacy(test);

    console.log(test__default['default']());

}(test));
```

It's different, but the result still doesn't contain the test function.

Comment: Please share your Rollup config.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the rollup config. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to change the `format` to `iife` ([Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)).

Your new `rollup.config.js` should look like this:

```js
// rollup.config.js

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/scripts/main.js',
        output: {
            name: 'main',
            file: "public/scripts/main.js",
            format: 'iife'
        }
    }
]
```

If you also need to use CommonJS exports (`module.exports = ___` instead of ES6 `export default ___`) you'll need to install [@rollup/plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs):

```sh
$ npm install --save-dev @rollup/plugin-commonjs
```

And use it like so:

```js
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/scripts/main.js',
        plugins: [commonjs()],
        output: {
            name: 'main',
            file: "public/scripts/main.js",
            format: 'iife'
        }
    }
]
```

On a side note, make sure your import paths are correct.

This:

```js
import test from "/test.js"
```

Should be:

```js
import test from "./test.js"
```

You can find more info in the [official docs](https://www.rollupjs.org/guide/en/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've done as you suggested and added the results in an edit.

Comment: Ah, that's because you're importing test from `/test` instead of `./test`. Rollup treats modules that it cannot find as external dependencies. I'll update the answer to include that.

Comment: Amazing, that makes a lot more sense now. I've updated my code and can confirm it works.

Comment: If that answers your whole question, would you mind marking the answer as correct? It helps me a lot :)